# Stripe CLI: How to resend events with nested metadata

Tags: stripe-payments, command-line-arguments

I'm using Stripe CLI to resend local webhook events. The command lets me set metadata using the following option / syntax: https://stripe.com/docs/cli/events/resend#events_resend-param

```
-d nested[param]=value
```

However the following attempts all result in a `Received unknown parameter` error.

```
stripe events resend event_id -d metadata[customer_id]=5678
stripe events resend event_id -d object[metadata][customer_id]=5678
stripe events resend event_id -d data[object][metadata][customer_id]=5678
stripe events resend event_id -d [data][object][metadata][customer_id]=5678
```

Anyone know how to successfully add nested params through the Stripe CLI?